# Health check for container

Tags: nginx, openresty

How can i create a healthcheck for container. I have nginx running as openresty container, and i am trying to create a health check. I followed the steps from https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2020/03/09/how-to-use-openresty-to-perform-health-checks/
But didnt have luck.
i keep getting: curl http://127.0.0.1:8090/health/http -v

404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the entire article?
In the mid section, it asks to add this.

```
location /ping {
    access_log off;
    default_type "text/html";
    return 200 "pong\n";
}

location /health/nginx {
    default_type "text/html";
    content_by_lua_file health/nginx.lua;
}
```

Note initially, the tutorial says

```
local url = "http://127.0.0.1"
```

but later, it's changed to

```
local url = "http://127.0.0.1/ping"
```